# Trying to resolve Invalid Use of NULL in Range(xx),Interior.ColorIndex

Tags: excel, null

I am trying to create a Macro in Excel that will find a range of cells to determine their color.

Here is the code that I am getting the Invalid Use of Null error:

```
Dim Result As Long
Result = Range("D8:N10").Interior.ColorIndex
```

SpreadSheet:

[image]

The cells contain a multi digit alpha code or can be blank.
I am trying to determine if the entire range is a specific color(green) and I will set a value in another cell.
There are other multiple rows in the cell that I can put through this and it works, this is the first one in the worksheet I came across that generated the error.

Comment: I am assuming the colors are set with conditional formatting?  If that is true then loop through the cells use the same test that colors the cells in your code.  If it finds one that is not true then they are not all filled with color.

Comment: Can you even get a range's color index like that? What happens if two cells have different index numbers?  You might have to loop through that range, checking each cell.

Comment: Do a search for the *CountColor* UDF.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer

```
Sub findCellColors()
    Dim i
    Dim d
    Dim Sets As Range 'the range where to set the colors to find
    Dim myData As Range 'the range of the data

    Set Sets = Range("Sets") 'the Sets and MyData are range names
    Set myData = Range("MyData")

    For Each i In Sets 'for each cell in the range("Sets")...
        For Each d In myData 'for each cell in the range("MyData")... Do this ==>
            If d.Interior.Color = i.Interior.Color Or _
               d.Value = 1 Then

               '#######################################
               ' You will compare every cell inside the data, if
               ' is the same color of the sets range
               ' that why d.Interior.Color = i.Interior.Color [OR]
               ' if the value of the "d" cell (d is the var where you store every cell
               ' of the data range) value is 1, because the conditional formatting is sets
               ' that way,(see the pictue 1)
               '#######################################

                i.Offset(0, 1).Value = i.Offset(0, 1).Value & " " & d.Address
                'here I just store the address of the colored cells, but you can do whatever you want...
            End If
        Next d
    Next i
End Sub
```

Well, inside the code you will see the comments.

I'm assuming two things:

1) You or other guy, or a macro, colored the cells and now you want to find that colors (now are like color-code to know something)

2) This colors are set by a conditional formatting, then on my code I set the condition after `OR` as you can see. If my guess is true (the conditional formatting think) then you need to set the same conditions in other cells, not check for the color, because the cells are not really colored, you see the color, but is not set as a property of the cell, just formatted to make you see that.

See this pictures to ilustrate:

[image]

And here is my data for this code:

[image]

If you have only conditinal formatting then you can use this:

```
Sub findCellColors2()
    Dim d
    Dim myData As Range 'the range of the data

    Set myData = Range("MyData")

        For Each d In myData 'for each cell in the range("MyData")... Do this ==>
            'Here we are not validating anything of the range Sets,
            'we are using it as a reference, to store the data...
            Select Case d.Value 'Mr. VBA please check the value of d
                Case 1 'then in case the value of d were 1
                    Range("O2").Value = Range("O2").Value & " " & d.Address
                Case 4
                    Range("O3").Value = Range("O3").Value & " " & d.Address
                Case 7
                    Range("O4").Value = Range("O4").Value & " " & d.Address
                Case 8
                    Range("O5").Value = Range("O5").Value & " " & d.Address
                Case Else
                    'do nothing or whatever you need.
            End Select 'this is equal to the conditional formating
        Next d
End Sub
```

[image]

That `Selece Case` check for ever cell to see if had the value you need to validate as you do with conditional formatting.

And here you can see the result:

[image]

Well it's all for today... if you need some improvement, just tell me and I will try to amplify the info.